# Piping the output of a command line tool to a script as a command line argument

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, pipe

I want to pass my IP address and a specific file to a program using xargs. For example, what I want to be able to do is:

`echo "(output of hostname -i) file.txt" | xargs myscript.rb`

What's the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
myscript.rb `hostname -i` file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use xargs, you can use backquotes inside your echo'ed string so as to instruct the shell that it should run the hostname commmand:

```
echo "`hostname -i` file.txt" | xargs myscript.rb
```

Otherwise, cppcoder's answer is the way to go.